# Conpot honeypot running issues

Tags: honeypot

Can somebody help me start [Conpot](http://conpot.org/), I get invalid syntax error when I run  one of the commands: `conpot`, `sudo conpot`, `conpot --template default`, after:

```
pip install conpot
```

On ubuntu 16.04. Thank you.

Comment: Put this question on askubuntu.com and soon you'll get a answer...

Comment: I don't think it has installed properly, what happens when you enter the command `which conpot`?

Comment: Hi and thank you. I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 lts and i followed the instructions for installing conpot from https://conpot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntu , after the command pip install conpot i get " Cannot fetch indx base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement conpot No distributions at all found for conpot". so i don`t now what to do next. I also tried steps with docker from https://github.com/mushorg/conpot/ and no luck .

Answer (score 1):

Kindly add more details to the question. I have installed using source file. Here are steps

`sudo apt-get install libsmi2ldbl snmp-mibs-downloader python-dev libevent-dev libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev`

`cd etc/opt`

`git clone https://github.com/glastopf/conpot.git`

`cd conpot`

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

`python3 setup.py install`

And to start conpot

`conpot -f --template default`

Comment: This answer helped more than the actual documentation.